# Like statement across multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, search, sql-like

I'm trying to query a like statement across multiple columns. I have the following search terms:
'dog'
'cat'
'rabbit'
'gerbil'
'guinea pig'
'hamster'

and I need search for these terms or terms LIKE these in the 'animals' table which has about 40 different columns. I am aware I can do the like statement by doing

```
 Select * from animals where [animalscolumn] like ('%dog%') or like ('%cat%') or like ('%gerbil%') or like ('%hamster%') or like ('%guinea pig%')
```

However the 'animalscolumn' isn't the only column I need to run the 'LIKE' statement across. I have to search for these terms in about 40 columns. Would anyone happen to know how? Thanks!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: You could use a temporary table like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1387797/7667467

Comment: Is this a one-off task or a part of a feature? For a one-off task, I'd use copy-paste / contextual replacement in my text editor to write the query with 240 clauses, and throw it away after the one-off task is done. For a feature, I'd look into full-text search capabilities of your database, or maybe into bolting in something like ElasticSearch to your app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23275971/330315  or http://stackoverflow.com/q/21979334/330315 or

Answer (score 3):

multiple `like` statements can not be used with `or` directly. You have to use `column name` for each `like` statement.

Use multiple like as mentioned below.

```
Select * 
from animals 
where 
(
[animalscolumn] like ('%dog%') or 
[animalscolumn] like ('%cat%') or 
[animalscolumn] like ('%gerbil%') or 
[animalscolumn] like ('%hamster%') or 
[animalscolumn] like ('%guinea pig%')
)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to search for the strings in multiple columns; your example searches in only one column.

Comment: Nope. he wants to search strings in one column. check his question. only one column mentioned with multiple or conditions.

Comment: Quoting OP:

> However the 'animalscolumn' isn't the only column I need to run the 'LIKE' statement across. I have to search for these terms in about 40 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a set of number you can use IN

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE columnId IN (154,156,133,157,119)
```

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT * from like1 WHERE tutorial_author LIKE '$apply'
OR
tutorial_title LIKE '$apply'";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if($mode == 'search_contact'){
// $prefix='%';

```
$apply=$dataObj['search'];
  $data = array();
  // $sql = "SELECT * from add_contact WHERE tutorial_author OR tutorial_title  LIKE '$apply'";
    $sql = "SELECT * from add_contact WHERE
    first_name LIKE '%$apply%'
             OR
    last_name LIKE '%$apply%'
           OR
    title LIKE '%$apply%'
         OR
    company LIKE '%$apply%'
             OR
    address LIKE '%$apply%'";


    $result = $myConnection->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // print_r($result->fetch_assoc());
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row['user_image'] = site_url.upload_dir.$row['image'];
      // print_r($row);
      $data[]=$row;


    }
    $array = array('status'=>true, 'message'=> 'contacts fetched successfully', 'data'=> $data);
          echo json_encode($array);
          exit;
  } else {
    $array = array('status'=>false, 'message'=> "No contacts available" );
          echo json_encode($array);
          exit;
  }
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from cscart_users 
where status like '%a' and user_type like '%c' and firstname like '%az%';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from cscart_users where status like '%a' and user_type like '%c'and firstname like'%az%';
```

syntax:

```
select * from tablename where columnname like'%b' and columnname2 like '%g';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a SQL Server stored procedure that takes a parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_SearchMultiple @SearchTerm nvarchar(256)  
AS
BEGIN
    SET @SearchTerm = '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
    SELECT TOP 100
        id, col1, col2, col3
    FROM
        asset_f
    WHERE
        col1 LIKE @SearchTerm OR col2 LIKE @SearchTerm OR col3 LIKE @SearchTerm 
    ORDER BY 
        id ASC
END
```